# Spring JPA: created timestamp getting flushed after subsequent call to save function

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment")
public class Payment {

   @Id
   private String transactionId;

   @CreationTimestamp
   private Timestamp createdTime;

   @UpdateTimestamp
   private Timestamp lastModifiedTime;

}
```

I am extending JPARepository

```
public interface PaymentRepository extends JpaRepository<Payment, Serializable> {
}
```

Inside my service class I am calling save function 2 times in following way:

```
paymentRepository.save(payment);
/* Some statements (can be some modifications to payment object)*/
paymentRepository,save(payment);
```

At the end I am finding value of createdTime as NULL in the database. In case second save statement is not executed in that case value of createdTime timestamp presents as expected.

What can be done so that I will not lose created timestamp ?

Comment: when you do modifications to payment object, just check if you are setting thhis to null

Comment: No. I am not setting it to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `CrudRepository`'s [API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-):

`<S extends T> S save(S entity)`
Saves a given entity. **Use the returned instance for further operations** as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.

Hence your code should read:

```
Payment p = paymentRepository.save(payment);
/* Some statements (can be some modifications to payment object)*/
Payment p2 = paymentRepository.save(p);
```

At least I guess so, please provide further info it this doesn't resolve your problem. (i.e. which JPA provider do you use?)

Comment: I am just wondering if implementation of save is async then p will be null if save takes some time(experienced this with mongorepository before). And I will end up saving p which can be null. Hibernate is JPA provider.

Comment: @VishalJamdade These methods run synchronously otherwise you would have something like `Future<Payment>` as a result type so no, the result `p` can't be `null`. Btw. was your problem solved with the modification? If yes, please mark this question as answered)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer of Robin, but additionally, multiple save method calls can be run in one transaction. If you want to be sure about the first command run on DB, my advice would be using **saveAndFlush()** method.

When you use **saveAndFlush()** method, you also commit the existing transaction, so that you can use the instance safely.

**Note: But there is a possibility that you increase the number of transactions to DB.**

Comment: If saveAndFlush() actually commits changes in database and not only flushes the JPA context then this solves my problem.

Comment: If your method is not annotated with @Transactional, you can see your changes just after you run saveAndFlush()